# Calculations in Cognito Forms based on Yes/No checkbox

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to create a calculation based on the "Yes/No" toggle field where "Yes" would add a cost to a Calculated total at the bottom.

I understand in general how to do calculations with checkboxes, but what is the code to use for the calculation to identify the toggle field in a section?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms.

This can be done by using a Price Field. In the Amount area you are going to be adding a calculation that checks to see if the Yes/No field is true or false, it will then add a price depending on what value it finds.

This is the calculation used with the Yes/No field titled "Yes No".

```
=YesNo ? 10 : 20
```

With this calculation the Yes or True value will be set to 10$ and the No or False value will be set to 20$.

[image]

[image]